# Use styling for ng-content from template component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I've created a template case component which I'm intending to use for multiple cases. To use the component as a template, I used `ng-content select=""`.

It works fine, but not completely as desired. For example:

- I have a div with a background image, its style is being configured inside of the template component:

```
<div class="front-image min-vh-100 min-vw-100" [style.transform]="'scale(' + scale + ')'">
</div>
```

To make this usable as a template, I replaced the given code with: `<ng-content select=".front-image"></ng-content>` and used the template inside of another component like this:

```
<app-case-template *ngIf="cases[3] as case">

  <div class="front-image min-vh-100 min-vw-100" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + case.image + ')'}"
       [style.transform]="'scale(' + scale + ')'">
  </div>

</app-case-template>
```

**How can I achieve the template to always get its styling from the template component** - right now I had to declare its styling inside of the new component to get it working. Additionally `[style.transform]` stopped working.

Is there something like a bypass?

Answer (score 0):

You may be going about this the wrong way. I'll try to outline a good way to do it. First, have a directory for your templates:

`templates
    - template.component.css   (generic styling)
    - template.component.html  (your markup)
    - template.component.ts    (your ts/js)`

Set up your `template.ts` for use:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'template-component',
  templateUrl: 'template.component.html'
  styleUrls: ['./template.component.css']
})
export class TemplateComponent {

}
```

Register it in your `component.module.ts` (or whatever you may have called it):

```
...
import {TemplateComonent} from './templates/template.component';
...
const exportedComponents = [
   SvgIconComponent
]
```

If needed, have your `shared.module.ts` export it:

```
import {ComponentsModule} from './components/components.module';
...
exports: [ComponentsModule]
```

Now you can use it like it's a custom HTML tag (your selector):

```
<template-component class="template"> </template-component>
```

**Now it will always grab the css styling from itself**, but you can stick a custom class in that tag as I have done, or call it like this from your main component's style page:

```
template-component {
   margin: 10px;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

There's a lot you can do including setting `@Input()` tags in your template that can be called from your HTML tag. You can also use Angular bindings to dynamically enter values or text into it. Many options here.

Note: instead of calling them templates, consider calling them shared components, or shared modals (if so). Have a directory called `shared > components` and have a `custom-name` directory with the like in there for organization.